# Xamarin Forms - Image Source Equal To Amazon S3 Url

Tags: xamarin.forms

So at the moment I am doing the following:

```
Image a = new Image {
   Source = "[amazon s3 url standard for acc]/YtxMBFww4nj7D3Xw/nR%2BjqAGY0k=",
   WidthRequest = 50,
   HeightRequest = 50
}
```

But the image displays nothing. I even copied the link into the browser and the image worked, but for some reason it doesnt work in xamarin forms. Could it be because of %2B and percent encoding.

PLEASE HELP THANK YOU

Comment: Can you supply the full url that you are using?

Comment: How are you using this image?  Are you placing it in the Page's Content property?

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
Image a = new Image {
   Source = new UriImageSource
        {
            Uri = new Uri("[amazon s3 url standard for acc]/YtxMBFww4nj7D3Xw/nR%2BjqAGY0k=")
        },
   WidthRequest = 50,
   HeightRequest = 50
};
```